# If first day of the month take value for the last day of the month - Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have the following dataset:
[image]

What I need is to correct the quantity amount i.e. if the day is the first day of the available dataset, take the quantity on the last day in this dataset in the previous month.

[image]

I am working on:
1. Added 2 col where I indicate the start of the month in the available dataset; in the 2nd col, I am indicating the last day of the month in the available dataset.

2. Then, I created a measure and the idea is that I am checking if the [date] is equal to [start_date]. If it is, I want to return the [quantity] from the [prev_month_end]. Otherwise, return [quantity] for the current date. I feel that I am very close, but not getting the desired result.po

```
start_date = STARTOFMONTH('tbl'[date])
prev_month_end= LASTDATE ( PREVIOUSMONTH ( 'tbl'[date] ))
```

```
quantity_corrected = 
var tdate = 'tbl'[prev_month_end]
var warehouse = 'tbl'[warehouse_code]
var prod_cat = 'tbl'[product_category]
var prod_typ = 'tbl'[product_type]

return
if(
    'tbl'[date]='tbl'[start_date],
    CALCULATE(
        FIRSTNONBLANK('tbl'[quantity],1),
        FILTER(
            ALL('tbl'), 
            'tbl'[product_category]=prod_cat && 
            'tbl'[prev_month_end] = tdate && 
            'tbl'[warehouse_code]=warehouse && 
            'tbl'[product_type]=prod_typ
        )
    ),
    'tbl'[quantity]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not completely sure I understand this but I think you only have to change one argument in the FILTER function.
Also, I added a second nested IF-statement (with the `temp` variable), otherwise the first row in the `[quantity_corected]` becomes blank.

```
quantity_corrected = 
var tdate = 'tbl'[prev_month_end]
var warehouse = 'tbl'[warehouse_code]
var prod_cat = 'tbl'[prod_category]
var prod_typ = 'tbl'[product_type]

return
if(
    'tbl'[date]='tbl'[start_date];
    var temp =
    CALCULATE(
        FIRSTNONBLANK('tbl'[quantity];1);
        FILTER(
            ALL('tbl');
            'tbl'[prod_category]=prod_cat && 
            'tbl'[date] = tdate &&  // <-- Changed from [prev_month_end]
            'tbl'[warehouse_code]=warehouse && 
            'tbl'[product_type]=prod_typ
        )
    )
    return
    IF(
        temp <> BLANK();
        temp;
        'tbl'[quantity]
    );
    'tbl'[quantity]
)
```

Resulting table:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You where pretty close, I corrected the comparison in the if and used Sum because I know I get only one row in the filter. Be aware, your logic is not working when you have gaps in your data. e.g. 31 Jan is missing..

```
quantity_corrected = 
    var tdate = 'tbl'[prev_month_end]
    var warehouse2 = tbl[warehouse_code]
    var prod_cat = tbl[prod_category]
    var prod_typ = tbl[product_type]
    var base_filter = FILTER(tbl; prod_cat = tbl[prod_category] && prod_typ = tbl[product_type] && warehouse2 = tbl[warehouse_code])
return 
    if (tbl[date] - 1 = tdate; 
        CALCULATE(SUM(tbl[quantity]);FILTER(base_filter;tbl[date] = tdate));
        tbl[quantity])
```

Comment: No worries about it. What I did is to do crossjoin of calendar[date], [warehouse_code], [product_type], [product_category], so in theory, I got all the combinations. Let me test the solution

Comment: Have you found the time to test?

Comment: thank you for following up! I marked Oscar's reply as a solution because he added the condition on how to deal with the very first record